# What is a good practice or design to swap algorithms at runtime?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have several data processing algorithms that can be assembled into a pipeline to transform data. The code is split into two components: A pre-processing component that does data loading-related tasks, and a processing pipeline component.

I currently have the two parts compiled and packaged into two separate jars. The idea is that the same pre-processing jar can be shipped to all customers, but the pipeline jar can be exchanged depending on customer requirements. I would like to keep the code simple and minimize configuration, so that rules out the use of OSGi or CDI frameworks.

I've gotten some hints by looking at SLF4J's implementation. That project is split into two parts: A core API, and a bunch of implementations that wrap different logging APIs. The core API makes calls to dummy classes (which exist in the core project simply to allow compilation) that are meant to be overridden by the same classes found in the logging projects. At build time, the compiled dummy classes are deleted from the core API before packaging into jar. At run time, the core jar and a logging jar are required to be included in the class path, and the missing class files in the core jar will be filled in by the files from the logging jar. This works fine, but it feels a little hacky to me. I'm wondering if there is a better design, or if this is the best that be done without using CDI frameworks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this probably belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com (see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you just have an interface that defines the methods in question?  Also, I can't help but think Dependency Injection would be a potential solution here.

Comment: @Powerlord  CDI frameworks like Spring will definitely solve the problem of swapping implementations, but all of the frameworks that I know require the use of configuration files, which I would like to avoid. Having an interface and using CDI framework goes hand-in-hand.

Comment: Spring doesn't require configuration files. You have problem for which dependency injection is perfect fit, be it via framework or some custom made. Other then configuration, you can always use reflection i guess.

Comment: @user3360241 You're right. Admittedly my understanding of CDI is limited. After taking another look, I see that dependency injection can be configured in many ways, be it manual file-based or through code annotations. This does seem like it's the way to go.

Comment: You might also be interested into checking out Spring profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

> **Example** Suppose we have a service type `com.example.CodecSet` which is
>   intended to represent sets of encoder/decoder pairs for some protocol.
>   In this case it is an abstract class with two abstract methods:
>
> ```
> public abstract Encoder getEncoder(String encodingName);
> public abstract Decoder getDecoder(String encodingName);
> ```
>
> Each method returns an appropriate object or `null` if the provider does 
>   not support the given encoding. Typical providers support more than one 
>   encoding. If `com.example.impl.StandardCodecs` is an implementation of 
>   the `CodecSet` service then its jar file also contains a file named
>
> ```
> META-INF/services/com.example.CodecSet
> ```
>
> This file contains the single line:
>
> ```
>  com.example.impl.StandardCodecs    # Standard codecs
> ```
>
> The `CodecSet` class creates and saves a single service instance at 
>   initialization:
>
> ```
> private static ServiceLoader<CodecSet> codecSetLoader
>     = ServiceLoader.load(CodecSet.class);
> ```
>
> To locate an encoder for a given encoding name it defines a static factory method which iterates
>   through the known and available providers, returning only when it has
>   located a suitable encoder or has run out of providers.
>
> ```
> public static Encoder getEncoder(String encodingName) {
>      for (CodecSet cp : codecSetLoader) {
>          Encoder enc = cp.getEncoder(encodingName);
>          if (enc != null)
>              return enc;
>      }
>      return null;  
> }
> ```
>
> A `getDecoder` method is defined similarly.

You already understand the gist of how to use it:

- Split your project into parts (core, implementation 1, implementation 2, ...)
- Ship the core API with the pre-processor
- Have each implementation add the correct META-INF file to its .jar file.

The only configuration files that are necessary are the ones you package into your .jar files.

You can even have them [automatically generated](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) for you with an annotation:

> ```
> package foo.bar;
>
> import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
>
> @AutoService(Processor.class) 
> final class MyProcessor extends Processor {
>   // … 
> }
> ```
>
> `AutoService` will generate the file
>
> ```
> META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
> ```
>
> in the output classes folder. The file will contain:
>
> ```
> foo.bar.MyProcessor
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the strategy software design pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: I agree that this is the Strategy pattern, but what I would like to know is how this can be implemented without the use of configuration files or program arguments.